# Change Latitude and Longitude with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with Lan/Lon in radians and and I want to change them to degrees. I know it can be done by iterating and 180/pi but I am serching for a simpler way to do it.

```
def MTS_Road_Coordinates(load):
data = pd.read_csv(load , delimiter=';')
roadCoordinates = []
for key , value in data.iterrows():
        roadCoordinates.append((tuple((data.at[key, 'ARS_GPS.GPSCycle.GPS_GEN_POS_FIX.Latitude'] * 180 / math.pi, data.at[key, 'ARS_GPS.GPSCycle.GPS_GEN_POS_FIX.Longitude'] * 180 / math.pi)) ,data.at[key, 'Time stamp']) )

return roadCoordinates
```

I would like to export the exact sane csv with degres

Comment: Try writing a function to calculate the conversion, then use `df.apply` (or in your case `data.apply`) which will map each radian to the function and return the degrees into a new column.

Comment: `df['lat'] = np.rad2deg(df['lat'])`, same for `lon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the columns to be converted into a list and use it as index, and call transform:

```
data = pd.read_csv(load , delimiter=';')
cols=[['ARS_GPS.GPSCycle.GPS_GEN_POS_FIX.Latitude','ARS_GPS.GPSCycle.GPS_GEN_POS_FIX.Longitude']]

data[cols]= data[cols].transform(lambda rad: rad*180/math.pi)

data.to_csv("new.csv",sep=";")
```

**Edit:**
Learning from @Quang Hoang's example, you can write:

```
data[cols]= np.rad2deg(data[cols])
```